# InvalidParameterValueError - Source bundle is empty or exceeds maximum allowed size: 524288000

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use eb cli to deploy django applicatoin.  It suddenly started showing error `InvalidParameterValueError - Source bundle is empty or exceeds maximum allowed size: 524288000` while deploying my app using `eb deploy` command. It showing error for both my production and stating environment.

My source bundle size should be below the limit.  What is the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [BeanStalk documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html), Your source bundle must meet the following requirements:

- Consist of a single ZIP file or WAR file (you can include multiple WAR files inside your ZIP file)
- Not exceed 512 MB
- Not include a parent folder or top-level directory (subdirectories are fine)

You can reduce the size of your source bundle by adding the unnecessary files to your .gitignore file.
You can estimate the folder sizes using the command `du -shc *` in the root directory of your application.

Comment: Thank you Ravi, is there a possibility we can upload it in zip file by chunk? Thank your Ravi in advance.

Comment: @Two, Beanstalk will not be able to combine your zip file parts. It will unzip the first file uploaded and if there is no sufficient files that complete the applicaiton, then it will probably give error in runtime even though if it shows upload as successful.

Comment: how do i do this when i am using the UI?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77394609/ui-source-bundle-is-empty-or-exceeds-maximum-allowed-size-524288000